# Parallel access to NTFS system from Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, windows-8, vmware, ntfs

I have the Windows 8.1 as a host system and I'm using the VMware with Ubuntu 12.04 for work. The virtual machine's disk is a physical partition on my SSD disk.
I wonder if is possible to have other, NTFS or FAT32 partitions which I would access (share) in parallel from host and virtual machine?

The question is if it will have a conflicts with files opened at the same time from both systems, or any other type of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use network file sharing to have the one (virtual) machine access files belonging to the other.  It could cause chaos if both systems tried to directly access the same disk at the same time.